# Countdown refresh button

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

I have implemented a refresh button of style UIBarSystemItem which will be disabled for 10s whenever it is pressed.

I want to further improve it by showing the time left before it is enabled. What is the quickest way to do it?

Many thanks in advance.

Called whenever the button is pressed.

```
-(void)refreshButton {
[self performSelector:@selector(enableRefreshButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
}

-(void)enableRefreshButton {
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
}
```

**EDIT: The refresh button is of style UIBARSystemItemRefresh**.

I am currently doing this as the answer suggests I use NSTimer. The button does get enabled and disable accordingly but the text doesn't change.

```
@inteface ... {
    int count;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UIBarButtonItem *refresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshButtonPressed)];          
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refresh;
}
-(void)refreshButtonPressed {
    //do something here...
    count = 10;
    self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimeLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)updateTimeLeft{
    count --;
    NSLog(@"%i", count);
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    if (count == 0) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
        [self.myTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Can I use the `title` property with UIBarButtonSystemItem?

Comment: Use the self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title property to change the title of the Bar Button

Comment: go through my updated answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to implement NSTimer
declare `int` variable `count` in .h file. and initialize it with `count==10` in `viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear` as your code goes.

call this method in performSelector

```
- (void)updateCount:(NSTimer *)aTimer { 
    count--;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
    NSLog(@"%i", count); 
    if (count == 0) { 
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR BAR BUTTON NAME"];
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    } 
}
```

**EDIT**

I think this link would definitely solved problem. This is almost same as you were asking. Please go through the link.  http://www.richardhyland.com/diary/2008/12/21/some-cool-tips-and-tricks-for-the-iphone-sdk/

Comment: could you please advise on my updated question, which uses NSTimer?

Comment: so what is problem?? is it not running??

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

Comment: I figured I can use NSTimer which has a property that returns the timeInterval left before the target is fired. But how do I set the button title to this timeInterval every second then?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a direct way to do that as far as I know. Alternatively you can maintain the seconds value manually (kind of counter) and increase it every time the target method is called(by scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval) and terminate the counter while invalidating the timer.